# how to count the words in a sentence in mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

How would I go about counting the words in sentence in database, example like this:

```
id words

1  bananas, mango, orange, watermelon

2  bananas, mango, orange, watermelon

3  bananas, mango, orange, watermelon

4  bananas, mango, orange, watermelon
```

I just want to count the number of mango, if i count and i get the result is : 4

this my query

```
"SELECT count(words)as total FROM fuit WHERE ?????";
```

?Which means I do not know how to use it with WHERE..

But how get like this with query in mysql and pdo?

Comment: Be a little more specific about what you are looking for. Do you want to know how many rows have the word 'mango' or do you want to know how many times 'mango' appears in each row

Comment: RST: sorry about my question is somewhat less clear, thanks already reminded. like you say i just want to know how many times 'mango' eppears in each row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no spaces in the `words` field (e.g. `bananas,mango,orange,watermelon`), you could use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('mango', words)
```

With spaces, you have to use regexes, for example:

```
SELECT ... WHERE words RLIKE '(^|, )mango($|,)'
```

Better yet, consider "normalizing" your data - make a separate `words` table:

```
id  word
1   mango
2   orange
etc
```

and a linkage table:

```
doc_id    word_id
1         1
1         2
etc
```

Comment: thanks for "normalizing" data, but this is like a "tags" this is any in one input text, and i dont kown how to normalizing because this Process in one insert.

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah: if these are tags, you should definitely normalize them. Think about renaming tags, removing a tag, etc. This will be very cumbersome with your current system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "mango" can only appear once in each row, you can use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to locate it. Note that `find_in_set` works on comma delimited strings, so you'd have to get rid of the whitespaces:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   fruit
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET ('mango', REPLACE(words, ' ', '')) > 0
```